# Can you spot the difference between my code and the tutorial?

Tags: css, menubar, drop-down-menu

Could someone tell me how exactly the code in my top navigation [here](http://www.namker.com/domains) differs from the one in [this tutorial](http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/)?

Other than changing the name of the menu id, the HTML and CSS I've used are the same. For some reason you can't actually see the menu on my site; its height is hidden for some reason. Before it was mysteriously hidden: even the drop-down sub-menu under the "domains" tab was not functional and the sub-menu items were being displayed in-line with the other list items of the primary ul. I'm totally lost.

Comment: Please add relevant pieces of your code directly to your question instead of using external links. Also your first link is broken.

Comment: I get no difference whatsoever. even the md5sums are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the CSS is not referencing the menu id. If you changed this the CSS might be trying to select that element with the given id and not finding it anymore. If this is the case update the CSS to use your new ID.